# Error importing Angular Material Module

Tags: angular, angular-material

im trying to add Angular Material to my Angular project but always getting this particular error.

[image: Here is the error on VSC Terminal]

I've already added

```
import {MatDialogModule} from '@angular/material/dialog'

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
   ...
  ],
  imports: [
   ...
   MatDialogModule
```

into my app.module.ts

And here i am wondering what did i do wrong when every time i tried importing the material module, the error says all other module is not found

Comment: share your package.json

Comment: https://codeshare.io/29VZ74 here, i already tried npm install @angular/material --save , or adding dependencies manually to package json.
Edited because i pressed enter prematurely

Comment: I can't access your link kindly update your question with your package.json

Comment: try `npm install --save @angular/animations` and tell me whats the o/p

Comment: @Vikas Here is my package json codeshare.io/29VZ74 , Im sorry this is my only 2nd question i put on SO i dont know how to update my question and i already tried installing both @angular/material and @angular/animation throught npm install but i still get the same errors

Comment: no, but it seems i might know why this error occurs. When i tried to npm install --save @angular/material , the npm shows **npm WARN @angular/material@6.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=6.0.0-beta.0 <7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.**. Does this mean i need to update my angular version to v.6? Is there a way i install the material module to match my current Angular version, since im afraid if i update my Angular version some of my code is not working

Comment: Mate if your angular version is 5 then use the same material version see [this](https://v5.material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview) They have provided a working stackblitz check out the dependency section and adjust your package.json accordinly else if your angular version is 6 check [this](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview) and do the same

Comment: You can install specific version of material `npm install --save @angular/material@5.2.4` and `npm install --save @angular/animations@5.2.11`

Comment: `npm install --save @angular/material` will pull latest version from repo

Answer (score 1):

you need to install material module `npm install --save @angular/material @angular/cdk` then declare in your app.module.ts file like below

```
import {MatDialogModule} from "@angular/material";

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        ...
        CourseDialogComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        ...
        MatDialogModule
    ],
    providers: [
       ...
    ],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    entryComponents: [CourseDialogComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: I already done that. Im sorry i didnt put enough information to my question

Comment: you may get reffrence from here https://stackblitz.com/edit/dialog-example?file=app%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: Turns out when i tried to npm install --save @angular/material , the npm shows **npm WARN @angular/material@6.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=6.0.0-beta.0 <7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.**. Does this mean i need to update my angular version to v.6? Is there a way i install the material module to match my current Angular version, since im afraid if i update my Angular version some of my code is not working

Comment: which version you use for angular?

Answer (score 1):

Alright it seems @Vikas has answered my question in the comment section. Turns out when im installing my material module through npm it automatically trying to install the latest version of the material module. In my case it didnt work because im still using angular 5 when the npm trying to install angular material v6^. Hence why this warning appears in the terminal after im trying to install it through npm >> **npm WARN @angular/material@6.2.1 requires a peer of @angular/core@>=6.0.0-beta.0 <7.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.**